# Antenna range calculation

Tags: antenna, bluetooth-low-energy, microstrip

I'm trying to build a microstrip antenna for my BLE module to increase its range. I'm more of a hardware Design and firmware guy and the last time I designed an antenna was in college back in 2015. Please excuse my trivial question.

After reading a lot I stumbled upon this Antenna: https://files.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Wifi_Bee_v2.0/res/Antenna_Datasheet.pdf

The spec impressed me relatively (other antennas) so I tried to calculate the range of this Antenna and I got some unbelievable results. I'm sure I did something wrong. I would really appreciate it if somebody points out my mistake or mistakes.

I got a range of 2.1KM for a 2.45GHZ antenna. I work with BLE products and the max range I saw was a little over 100m. I used the following website to calculate the range. 
https://www.rfwireless-world.com/calculators/Antenna-Range-Calculator.html

My parameters are as follows (Got em from the datasheet of the antenna)

Antenna gain: 1.5 dB
transmit power: 3 W (34.77db)
operating frequency: 2400MHz
cable loss: 9.5 dB
receiver sensitivity: -80

Thank you

Comment: Try the same with 10 mW instead of 3W.

Comment: The antenna data sheet says 3 watts maximum so maybe you can pump it with 1 watt continuous. Then you have your conversion from electrical power to emitted  power ratio - do you know what that antenna specifies in this respect? I bet it's 10 dB or more down.

Comment: To explain what @BrianDrummond wrote: that's the power rating of the antenna, i.e. how much power you *can* push through. It's not how much power your transmitter pushes through – that's legally and technically restricted, and 10 mW is already a rather generous estimate for a BLE device. So, your power estimate is off by a factor of 300, and that means your range estimate (if it's correct based on the 3W, didn't check) would be too high by a factor of \$\sqrt{300}\$ (since power drops with the square of distance, having 300 times less power is equivalent to being \$\sqrt{300}\$ times farther.)

Comment: 10mW is 10db, then I get a range of 125 which is high but still reasonable. So the lesson here is I can't run an Antenna at its max power like voltage regulator etc. 

What's the max power I can run it at. As Andy suggested, If I run it a 1W that's 30db. That's a range of 1.25KM. Not practical. Else others would have done it.

How do I know the limit? It is not specified in the datasheet.

Comment: it's not 10 dB, it's 10 dBm; don't confuse your units, or you will get very confused very quickly :) You can of course run your antenna at its maximum power, but a transmitter usually doesn't do that. and the 10 dBm would be, as both Brian and I said, a good estimate for what your BLE module does. The restriction is not your antenna, it's the transmitter module, and law.

Comment: To increase the range, you need more radiated power. That either means a more powerful amplifier, like delivering (an illegal for BLE) +30dBm (note the dBm units for power! dB with respect to 1mW), or a directional antenna, which has more gain than an isotropic to send more power in a specific direction (still illegal for BLE, and not useable at all as a mobile antenna, only as a fixed link). The max power handling of the antenna is irrelvant as long as it's above the max power of the transmitter.

Comment: The "limit" will not be in the datasheet.  There are laws that tell you how much power you are allowed to use.  The range depends on the power, the antenna, and the sensitivity of the receiver.  The antenna datasheet can't tell you most of that.

Comment: If you search "BLE transmit power" it won't be hard to find the maximum permitted power for BLE, and it's 10 mW. More than that would unacceptably interfere with other services.

Comment: 'km' for kilometer, 'dB' for decibel, 'Hz' for hertz.

Comment: Thank you all. I kinda got a better understanding what how the BLE range is limited. I'll do further research the build my own Antenna for my BE model.